# To remove a particular element from the xml-string using lxml Python 3.5

Tags: python, xml, lxml, python-3.5

I have the below xml as an input to a function of python. I want to find a particular element which has Null value((firstChild.nodeValue)) and totally delete that from the xml and return the string. I have a contingency of using only the lxml module. Can I get help with this.

```
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank></rank>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E">345</neighbor>
</country>
```

I want the output to be:-

```
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E">345</neighbor>
</country>
```

I basically have the flexibility with a constant list containing tag names where I can iterate and find the text.Below is the list.
a= ('rank','year','a','b','gdppc','neighbor')

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union to look for all nodes in a single xpath, then presuming you want to remove nodes with no text you can just call `tree.remove(node)`:

```
x = """<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank></rank>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E">345</neighbor>
</country>"""

from lxml import etree


tree = etree.fromstring(x)

a = ('rank','year','a','b','gdppc','neighbor')

for node in tree.xpath("|".join(map("//{}".format, a))):
    if not node.text:
        tree.remove(node)
print(etree.tostring(tree).decode("utf-8"))
```

Which would give you:

```
<country name="Liechtenstein">
<year>2008</year>
<gdppc>141100</gdppc>
<neighbor name="Austria" direction="E">345</neighbor>
</country>
```

Comment: Hello Padriac, I get the lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix error. Sorry I updated my questionwith actual xml which has namespaces. Your answer worked for my previous sample xml without namespaces. BAsically with the namespaces in the tags, it was not able to evaluate the xpath i guess.

Comment: 'for node in tree.xpath("|".join(map("//{}".format, a))):
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1587, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:57803)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:166824)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:165783)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix'

Comment: @sreenimmala, yes as  your edits completely changed your question,  the answer you provided is not remotely close to answering what you originally asked

Answer (score -1):

The below code worked :)

```
def remove_empty_elements(self,xml_input):
    tree = etree.fromstring(xml_input)
    for found in tree.xpath("//*[text()=' ']"):
        print("deleted " + str(found))
        found.getparent().remove(found)
    print(etree.tostring(tree).decode("utf-8"))
```